# ActiveMQ ProtocolException Invalid message encoding

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

I am able to publish & subscribe messages through ActiveMQ broker without using SSL.

Now I want to use ActiveMQ with SSL.I am using self-signed certificates.

I followed the steps given in this link : http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html
for setting up my broker.

As I have to use the certificates in .pem format for my embedded device,I have converted certificates into .pem format.

When I try to connect esp32 / [MQTTfx](http://mqttfx.org/) (desktop application) to the broker ***I get the below error message from the broker:***

```
2020-06-15 12:10:14,037 | DEBUG | Transport Connection to: tcp://---.---.1.5:35182 failed: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid message encoding | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///---.---.1.5:35182@1883


java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid message encoding
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.codec.MessageSupport.readUTF(MessageSupport.java:63)[mqtt-client-1.12.jar:1.12]
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.codec.CONNECT.decode(CONNECT.java:79)[mqtt-client-1.12.jar:1.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTCommand(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:200)[activemq-mqtt-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTTransportFilter.onCommand(MQTTTransportFilter.java:94)[activemq-mqtt-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_92]


2020-06-15 12:10:14,040 | DEBUG | Unregistering MBean org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,connector=clientConnectors,connectorName=mqtt,connectionViewType=remoteAddress,connectionName=tcp_//---.---.1.5_35182 | org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///---.---.1.5:35182@1883
2020-06-15 12:10:14,041 | DEBUG | Stopping connection: tcp://---.---.1.5:35182 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2185

2020-06-15 12:10:14,041 | WARN  | Exception occurred processing: 
MQTTFrame { type: unknown, qos: AT_MOST_ONCE, dup:false }: org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolException: Unknown MQTTFrame type: 0 | org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///---.---.1.5:35182@1883

2020-06-15 12:10:14,042 | DEBUG | Exception detail | org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///---.---.1.5:35182@1883
org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolException: Unknown MQTTFrame type: 0
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter.onMQTTCommand(MQTTProtocolConverter.java:230)[activemq-mqtt-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.mqtt.MQTTTransportFilter.onCommand(MQTTTransportFilter.java:94)[activemq-mqtt-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_92]
2020-06-15 12:10:14,042 | DEBUG | Stopping transport tcp:///---.---.1.5:35182@1883 | org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2185
2020-06-15 12:10:14,045 | DEBUG | Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@384c5a21[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] | org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2185
2020-06-15 12:10:14,047 | DEBUG | Closed socket Socket[addr=/---.---.1.5,port=35182,localport=1883] | org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport | ActiveMQ Task-1
2020-06-15 12:10:14,049 | DEBUG | Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@384c5a21[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1] | org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2185
2020-06-15 12:10:14,054 | DEBUG | Stopped transport: tcp://---.---.1.5:35182 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2185
2020-06-15 12:10:14,056 | DEBUG | Connection Stopped: tcp://---.---.1.5:35182 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2185
```

***Below is the error message i get from the MQTTfx:***

```
INFO --- BrokerConnectorController      : onConnect
INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel             : MqttClient with ID xxxxxx assigned.
ERROR --- MqttFX ClientModel             : Error when connecting
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: MqttException
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:715) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:108) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]
... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:108) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]
... 7 more
ERROR --- MqttFX ClientModel             : Please verify your Settings (e.g. Broker Address, Broker Port & Client ID) and the user credentials!
```

Using MQTT version 3.1.1 on both broker and client.

So what is that I am missing?
Any help on this will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Most likely you are either connecting the client using SSL to the non-SSL port on the broker or the reverse

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Yes you are right I was using the wrong Port number.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the loop on this one.  The user was attempting to connect either from a TCP connection to an SSL connection or from SSL to the TCP accepting port on the broker which caused this message to be given due to the contents of the binary payload not being able to be decoded into valid protocol types.

Connecting to the correct port resolves this issue.